# C# MVC - Render Section does not load CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rendering

I have defined this bit of code in the `<head>` section of my `_Layout` page.

```
@RenderSection("Styles", false)
```

Then my `index` page

```
@section Styles {
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~Views/zCSS/ManualProposalWindow.css")" />    
}
```

My Index page is in `Views/Home/Index`

My CSS is in `Views/CSS/ManualProposalWindow.css`

I know the styles are correct because if I put them in a style block inside the index it works fine.

This is the CSS I'm trying to load:

```
body {
       background: black;
}
```

Comment: Troubleshooting questions: 1) Load the page. Is the link element in the markup? 2) Using Firebug's network tab, is the stylesheet resource downloading correctly?

Comment: Can StyleSheets only be referenced in the Content folder?? because when I put in the content folder it worked fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files within the `views` folder cannot be loaded. They will throw a 404 error due to the `httpHandler` configured in the `Web.config` there. This is for security, as you do not want your .cshtml files publicly accessible.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Include the css file from any other folder and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks for the knowledge, I thought it was something obscure like this after it worked when I switched locations

Answer (score 5):

Your index page should be like this:

```
@section Styles
{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/styleFile.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/orStyleBundle")
}
```

Also, put your styles in the `Content` (or similar) folder in your solution.

Comment: I get an error: `The name 'Styles' does not exist in current context`. Perhaps I'm on a different version of C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
@section Styles {
            <style>
                .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
                    background-color: none;
                }
        
                .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
                    background-color: none;
                }
            </style>   
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).